# How to show Currency symbol as a prefix on Amount in order email template in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, order-email

In Order Email Template we used var order.getTotal,var order.getSubTotal,When we used this variable currency symbol is not showing.How to show it Plz guide me.

This is screenshot where i want currency symbol: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ghQ5.png
module_sales/view/forntend/email/order_new.html
`

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Your %store_name order confirmation" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message",
"var order.getSubtotal()":"Order Subtotal"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
`
This is New Template in admin :`{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<td class="wid50" style="width:50%;padding:5px 10px;    text-align: left;"><p style="color:grey">Hi <b style="color:#000;">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</b></p>
</td> 
<td class="wid50" style="width:50%;padding:5px 10px;    text-align: right;"><p style="color:grey">{{trans 'Order Placed to <b style="color:#000;"><span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |formatDateTime: Y-m-d|raw}}</b><p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="wid50" style="width:50%;padding:5px 10px;    text-align: left;"><p style="color:grey;">Your order has been successfully placed.</p> 
</td>
<td class="wid50" style="width:50%;padding:5px 10px;    text-align: right;">
<p style="color:grey;">
{{trans 'Order Number <b style="color:#000;"></b<span class="no-link">%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br /><br />

<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="border: 1px solid #139b3b;">
<tr>
<td class="wid50" style="width:50%;vertical-align: top;padding:5px 10px;    text-align: left;"><p style="float:left">Delivery by <span style="color:#139B3B"> {{var order.getDeliveryDate()}}</span></p>



</td>

<td class="wid50" style="width:50%;vertical-align: top;padding:5px 10px;    text-align: right;">
<p class="centrtext"><b>Delivery Address</b></p> 
 <p class="centrtext"><span>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</span></p>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="wid50" style="width:50%;vertical-align:top;padding:5px 10px;    text-align: left;">
  <p style="float:left">Amount Paid <span style="color:#139B3B">{{var order.getGrandTotal()}}</span></p> 

  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="padding:5px 10px;">
 <p>You will receive the next update when the item in your order is packed/shipped by the seller.</p>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
<br /><br />
 <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
 <tr>
 <td class="wid20" style="    width: 20%;text-align: center;padding: 5px 10px;border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;background: #e8e8e8;">
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}} 
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
<br /><br />
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
 <tr>
 <td style="text-align:right;padding:5px10px;">
 <p class="centrtext"><span><b>Item(s) Total:</b> {{var order.getGrandTotal()}}</span></p>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="text-align:right;padding:5px 10px;">
<p class="centrtext"><span><b>Amount Paid:</b> {{var order.getGrandTotal()}}</span></p>
 </td>
 </tr>


 </table>

  <footer>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="text-align:center">
<tr>
<td style="padding:5px 10px;">
 <p  style="text-align:left"><b>Thank you for shopping with Fox Ministry!</b></p>
</td style="padding:5px 10px;">
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>
<p>Got Questions? Please get in touch with our Customer Care at <b>+91 (11) 41066756</b> (ALL DAYS | 9AM TO 10PM)

</p>
</td>
</tr>
  </table>
</footer>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}`
```

Comment: it's your custom template or magento default template?

Comment: Its custom template

Comment: Did you create observer or controller for that ? Then, post code here please.

Comment: I will override file module_sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html.In this file we create two variable.Code is

Comment: Upload your all files code which is related to price.

Comment: i will updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85831/discussion-between-lovely-setia-and-rohan-hapani).